# How do I access the text from a select, not the selected option text but what appears in the select pane?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, translation

I am writing a generalized jQuery translation plugin and have run into a problem with the text appearing in the select area, which does not get translated. For example, here is an English select:

```
<select>
    <option value=" = 0">Choose an option</option>
    <option value=" = 1">one</option>
    <option value=" = 2">two</option>
    <option value=" = 3">three</option>
</select>
```

When rendered, the select shows "Choose and option" above a drop-down box.

After translation:

```
<select>
    <option value=" = 0">Choisisez une option</option>
    <option value=" = 1">un</option>
    <option value=" = 2">dues</option>
    <option value=" = 3">trois</option>
</select>
```

But when rendered, the select text shows "Choose and option" in English, even though the automatic default option is translated.

My selector is `$("select option")` and I have also tried `$("select>option)`.

How can I reference this so the default text is shown in French. I would prefer a jQuery selector string answer, that is without any .find, .parent etc.

**UPDATE**
Please let me emphasize, it has nothing to do with the plugin code. This is purely a jQuery selector question. The last thing I tried was "select option:nth-child(1):parent" which did not solve the problem.

Here is a [link to the site](http://test.bunkerhill.com/) that will illustrate what I mean. Just choose a language from the drop-down box at the top right of the page.

Comment: So you're asking us why your plugin isn't working, even if we've never seen said plugin ?

Comment: No. That is not fair. The plugin works fine, but I do need help with the jQuery selector.

Comment: _"I am writing a generalized jQuery translation plugin"_ Can include plugin text at Question ? , create stacksnippets to demonstrate ? _"After translation:"_ Where is `html` after translation viewed ? At `console` ?

Comment: I have posted a link to a website that illustrates what I am encountering.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").children(":selected").text();
```

Will get the text of the selected option.

To get text of each option:

```
$("select").children("option").each(function() {
    $(this).text();//Do something with the text
});
```

To get the text of the third option:

```
$("select").children("option:nth-child(2)");
```

.children() can be combined with $("select ") but I wrote children() because that makes it possible to replace the select with a variable or $(this).

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. I know how to get the selected option text, I need the text that is displayed in the select area.  Please re-read the question.

Comment: The text displayed in the select area is the selected option text. There is no text besides that in the html select element.

Comment: But it is when you are talking about translations as I explained. Please re-read the question.

Comment: I read it and in the html you mentioned there is no other text element beside the option elements, it might be possible that there is an additional text element showing text for select but that's not mentioned in the question. We can't guess how your plugin code works.